# CW Models in Hatcher

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

[image]

So I don't understand the reasoning for the last line. Why does $(Z',A')$ being an $n'$-connected CW model for $(X',A')$ implies that the relative groups $\pi_i(W,Z')$ are zero for $i>n'$. I would appreciate some help. I tried looking at the exact sequence of pairs, but I don't see where the $n$-connectedness comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An n-connected CW model $(Z',A') \to (X',A')$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_k(Z') \to \pi_k(X')$ for k > n'. Since $\pi_k(W) \simeq \pi_k(X')$ the long exact sequence for the pair $(W,Z')$ tells us that $\pi_k(W,Z') = 0$ for k > n'